# How to re-size container to fit width of its children

Tags: html, css

I have two squares inside of a container that are overlapping using transform: translate and I want to remove the padding to the right of the blue square so that the container perfectly fits the width of the children. Please see image for clarification.

[Picture of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYiMg.png)

I’ve tried sizing the container to `90px`, which should be the width of the children `(50px + 50px - 10px)`, but when I do this the blue box drops to the next row. Why does it do this? I also tried applying `padding-right: 0` but nothing changed.

```css
.container {
  width: 110px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.one {
  background: red;
}

.two {
  background: blue;
  transform: translate(-10px, 15%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box one"></div>
  <div class="box two"></div>
</div>
```

I would like there to be no left or right padding.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute` with `top` and `left`/`right`, don't forget `position: relative` on the container:

```css
.container{
  width: 90px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-right: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.box{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.one{
  background: red; 
}

.two{
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box one"></div>
  <div class="box two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Does transform: translate automatically add padding? Just trying to figure out why I should use absolute positioning instead of transform translate.

Comment: @CraigKleila in the current snippet it's not the only thing that creates padding. I understand that you want to put the blue box next to the red box, but using `display: inline-block` has some consequences. One of them is that because your `<div>`s have space between them (2 spaces and a new line, doesn't matter how much, gets compressed to a single space) browsers will add automatically a space between them. If you put them next to each other you'll lose a bunch of pixels. Now you can go to `100px` width but doing less will cause a line break, since it's calculated before transform.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a negative margin-right to second square

```css
.container {
  width: 94px;
  height: 57px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.one {
  background: red;
}

.two {
  background: blue;
  margin-right: -10px;
  transform: translate(-10px, 15%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box one"></div>
  <div class="box two"></div>
</div>
```